# OS installation from inside Windows

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multi-boot, operating-systems

I have a broken screen laptop, which I connect to an old-ish screen with an HDMI to VGA adapter.

I want to install a Linux distribution. I won't specify which, because maybe there is a certain one that can help with this problem. If there is, suggest it, but I'm mainly thinking about Arch, Ubuntu or Debian.

The problem is that I can't boot into BIOS/UEFI without my main laptop screen, which I don't have any access to, since it's broken.

I have tried closing the laptop lid to force output to external screen - doesn't seem to work, and moving my hard drive to another computer to install the OS and then back to my laptop is also not an option.

So my last resort is to install the new OS from inside Windows. Is such a thing possible? Using something like windows' dual boot. (or any method. I just don't want Windows on my computer any more)

I have Windows 10, with an internal and an external hard drive (if having an external hard drive solves anything). I have UEFI, not Legacy.

Answer (score 1):

If you can still use Windows, you can try WUBI to perform a guided Ubuntu dual-boot or if you wanted Linux "inside" Windows, you could try VirtualBox or VMWare.

Comment: WUBI does not seem to work for Windows 8 / 10 according to their wiki, and I have Windows 10. Using a virtual box is also not a option. I want to change my OS, not to test a new one.

Comment: On my laptop, you can press `Fn + F12` to choose a boot device. You could look up if your device has a boot key or combination of keys and then create a USB Boot Device with Rufus or Win32DiskImager.